# Samsung Galaxy A5 (A500FU) - Installing Custom ROMs impossible

Tags: samsung, rom, twrp, odin

I took the CyanogenMod for my device (Galaxy A5 aka A500FU) from this thread:
http://forum.xda-developers.com/samsung-a-series/development/dev-help-to-create-cm12-rom-galaxy-a5-t3153129I took the zip file and put it on my sd card, opened up TWRP and wiped all (of course I made backups) and flashed it. But there was the error:
error executing updater binary in zip

I tried in Odin, but there comes an "unexpected" error. Of course I've also tried to put the zip in a tar file, but it still does not work at all...

What am I doing wrong?
Thank you

Comment: Best place for getting help with this issue you've already linked to: The XDA thread you got that ROM from. There you find people using it, and with some luck even the one creating the ROM might be active there – who is the one who should know best.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it earlier, but for all others: I downloaded TWRP from another developer, now it works flawlessly.

Comment: Can you link the source from where you downloaded that another TWRP?

Comment: Answers like "I did it", "I fixed it" does not help the future visitors. Please provide the actual solution on how you did it.